# How can I disable / permanently hide the taskbar in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, powershell, hide, taskbar

I would like to completely remove the Windows 7 taskbar, including tray and start-button, so that the user can not reactivate it by pressing the Windows-key on the keyboard. however, all other explorer functionality (i.e. starting an explorer Window using Windows+E) should remain.

Is it possible to permanently hide the complete taskbar? Maybe there are some registry values on could change in order to make that behaviour selectable using a powershell script?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Here be my solution (it hides rather than replaces or removes the native taskbar - this allows it to work with programs that have a dependency on the native taskbar, such as display fusions taskbar).

[disable-taskbar-always-top](http://www.eightforums.com/software-apps/11066-disable-taskbar-always-top.html#post275120)

### Still to solve: [HALF SOLVED]

- Eliminate the stupid line that auto-hide leaves with some maximized applications, such as Google Chrome

### HALF SOLUTION -

If you move the taskbar to the left or right edge prior to doing the above steps, you don't get the stupid auto-hide line at the top or bottom of Google Chrome. Since the native taskbar is not mouse sensitive anymore, it won't impact your use of hot corners, or multi monitors (for instance I have the native taskbar on the left of my middle monitor, and it does not popup when moving between monitors using the steps in this post).

Okay, I think I have finally - finally - got a workaround that:

- Keeps the native Windows 7/8 taskbar hidden for your session (you do have a couple of steps you need to do on start-up each time, or if you manually un-hide the taskbar).
- Prevents the native Windows 7/8 taskbar from opening with popups or programs seeking attention (flashing taskbar thing).
- Prevents the native taskbar from being mouse sensitive (i.e. despite auto-hide, it will not appear when you mouse over the hidden taskbar anymore).
- Allows you to use the screen area that is occupied by the native taskbar (this is the problem of not combining Taskbar-Hide with the autohide setting; you can't use that screen real-estate).
- Allows you to run alternative taskbars that are dependent on keeping the native taskbar functional (for instance Dislay Fusions Multi-Monitor Taskbar + [Settings >> Advanced Settings ?> 'Show On All Montiors'])

### One Time Steps:

1) Download and run this registry edit to prevent balloon notification popups from the native taskbar/system tray:
Notifications - Enable or Disable Message Balloons - Windows 7 Help Forums
(You can open this in notepad to see what changes it will make prior to installing it, if you want).

2) Download and run Taskbar-Hide from here:
Hide Taskbar: Hide Taskbar in Windows 8 | 7 with a hotkey
3) Set the taskbar to auto-hide

### Optional:

3) B) Add a shortcut to Taskbar-Hide.exe in your startup folder, to have it launch automatically with windows on startup (you still need to use the Ctrl+Esc hotkeys to activate the functions of taskbar-hide - though you could also script this if you were really keen).

### Startup Folder:

C:\Users{User Name}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
Steps to hide taskbar after each start-up or manually un-hiding using Taskbar-Hide

4) Make sure Taskbar-Hide is running.

5) Make sure the taskbar is in its auto-hide state (i.e. you'll have to look at any programs that are currently seeking attention).

6) Once the taskbar is 'auto-hidden', press the hotkeys for Taskbar-Hide (Ctrl+Esc)

[This should mean that the native taskbar area is no longer sensitive to mouse activity]

Answer (score 1):

One way is to replace the explorer shell with your own shell. This is the  a common method done in Windows 7 Embedded.

In older versions of Windows (such as XP) it was possible to specifiy a shell for each user via regedit. I am not sure this is easily possible in Windows 7.

See https://superuser.com/questions/352865/how-do-i-change-the-windows-shell-for-only-one-user

Comment: When I replace the explorer shell in Win7 with my own EXE, it works, but as soon as I manually start any explorer-instance, the Windows taskbar pops up. Is that intended?

Answer (score 1):

Make an empty exe file and use it as the file to use in your "Custom User Interface" group policy. Additional information [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20514/User-Interface-Replacement-for-Explorer).

Comment: The problem with that solution is that as soon as I start any explorer process in Windows, the taskbar will be displayed :(

Answer (score 0):

I have found another solution that works nearly perfect for me, by just hiding the Taskbar and the Start button by simply sending both the `WM_HIDE` message:

```
Handle = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", "");
...
ShowWindow(Handle, SW_SHOW);
```

The only problem I have with that solution is that the taskbar is not hidden permanently, i.e. as soon as one element is activated that does not have the focus, which on the taskbar leads to the item flashing in yellow, the taskbar gets visible again.

I'm not sure if there is a way to prevent Windows from re-enabling the visible flag of the taskbar in some way, or a method to hook to the `SW_SHOW` in C# though.