# How to keep taskbar bottom of other windows?

Tags: java, taskbar

I try to make an application which must be full screen. But when i press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> task manager comes up. Even i disable task manager, at this time its error message comes up and make taskbar visible. Then user get the chance to go to the dekstop but i dont want user to get this chance. Only user could be able to go to desktop when it did what application wants from it. So i need taskbar keep bottom of other windows until user does what it should do. And i need to do this by my application which i try to code in Java

How can i change the status of task bar using registry?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to keep the user hostage of your application (the only reasons I can think of are not very ethical)?

Comment: Nope. I want to do that for a good reason :D

Comment: I think you need to change your windows settings,this may go very critical in Java.

Comment: But how can i do it by java without reseting the machine?

Comment: Which version of OS you are using

Comment: @assylias - there are many legitimate situation where you would want to "lock" a computer down under your own, custom shell. Public kiosk-mode/appliance type terminals, for instance.

Comment: @pap Agreed, in which case the solution is generally to use a customised OS I believe.

Comment: @assylias In my experience, the general solution is to write an application and run it modal in full-screen mode. Customizing and maintaining an OS is way beyond the scope of most companies. If only for the fact that it's a lot easier to find someone to develop and maintain a Java or C# application than someone who can re-skin and customize a *nix distro. I've seen a lot of information-kiosks, ATM:s and "smart" vending machines that ran a modal, full-screen application on top of the OS. Not sure I've seen one that ran a customized OS.

Comment: But when i use a dialog box and make it toolkit modal same problem occurs again. User still can get the chance to reach task bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found it.

When i changed the value of 8th byte value of Settings variable to 10 in

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects2

in registery

It just deselect the "Keep the task bar on top other windows" option

For applying the changes explorer.exe should be killed and re run

Answer (score 0):

Why not permanently disable the taskbar?

Follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869335/how-can-i-disable-permanently-hide-the-taskbar-in-windows-7) to permanently disable the task bar.

You can edit `.reg` files in Java, follow [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611067/how-to-run-reg-file-in-java-netbeans-code) to know how to edit `.reg` files

*"But how can i do it by java without reseting the machine?"*

As far as i came across, you have to reboot your system, no way out.

Answer (score 0):

There are key strokes which Windows catches before they are sent to application and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> is one of those.

Regarding "Then user get the chance to go to the dekstop", if you set frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);, user won't be able to switch to other any application.

Answer (score -1):

You can use java's fullscreen API, and then use a Robot to force focus back to your application. See here: [Java Full Screen Program (Swing) -Tab/ALT F4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462454/java-full-screen-program-swing-tab-alt-f4).
Good luck in whatever you are doing - it doesn't sound fun!

Comment: CTRL+ALT+DEL  is a issue here.